# Wagtail how to separate custom page types in sidebar

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to add custom pages in the admin sidebar and remove the "Pages" link. I want to have different links such as:

- Blog Posts
- Pages
- Events
- Games

Shown in the sidebar and each listing page only shows items based on the custom page. I have been looking in the documentation and the only thing that I found was to add custom URLs to the sidebar but I need to also add custom pages to show listings.

Answer (score 2):

The [ModelAdmin](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) module allows you to register page models to appear as new items in the admin menu.

You can add `exclude_from_explorer = True` to your ModelAdmin definition to hide a page type from the main page explorer, although that won't hide the Pages menu item itself - for that, you would need to define a [`construct_main_menu`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#construct-main-menu) hook to run after the menu has been built, and remove it from the list.